# The Procedure Entry Point _gxx_personality_vo could not be located in the dynamic library

Tags: c++, user-interface

I am a learner of C++ Programming and currently I would like to develop a small GUI Windows using Win32 application.
I am using CodeBlocks as my IDE and MinGW compiler.
I am able to successfully run my Programm and create GUI when I run through my IDE. But after the creation of .exe file If I try to open I am getting the following error(image attached).

I found few solutions in online for similar problems asking to link libraries in IDE but I do not no the specific name of library to be linked. If this does not sound to be a solution I would like to get other suggestions also from you.
It would be very grateful if someone could help me in this regards.

[Error during the application run](https://i.stack.imgur.com/66Lxf.png)Thanks

Anil

Comment: If your codes compiling you shouldn't need to worry about linking to extra libraries. Make sure any of your DLL's are included in your path or run your executable from the same location as your DLL's

Comment: @Tom thanks for reply. Can you please Elaborate what you exactly mean? To be specific, how to make sure the same location?

Comment: Your executable and other binaries (e.g DLL's) need to be in the same directory. It does not matter where this directory is. Alternatively, add the locations of your executable and your DLL's to your systems "PATH" environment variable

Comment: @Tom I have added PATH to DLLs in my system but still the error pursuits

Comment: Problem has been solved by copying the DLL files wherever you place your application file.

Comment: Great, please delete the question